# SQL Server 2005 Query between two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got two tables (see below), RM and RP. In the RP Table below, the Provider key can have many RegionIds (key) associated with it. Can I create a query that will allow me to return a Provider with all of their associated RegionIds (using the RP table) and also grab the RegionIds respective ClientNum from the RM Table?

```
RM Table                      RP Table
--------                      --------
RegionId   key                RegionId   key
..                            Provider   key
..
ClientNum
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? This seems like a straight forward inner join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT P.*, RM.RegionId, RM.ClientNum
FROM Provider P
INNER JOIN RP ON P.ID = RP.Provider
INNER JOIN RM ON RM.RegionId = RP.RegionId
```

You will get a row for each provider/clientNum association

[Edited to reflect comment]

Comment: I tried the following but it says Region is an invalid object name.

SELECT     P.*, RegionMaster.RegionId AS Expr1, RegionMaster.ClientNum AS Expr2
FROM         Provider P
INNER JOIN RegionProvider ON P.ID = RegionProvider.Provider
INNER JOIN Region R ON R.ID = RegionProvider.RegionId
INNER JOIN RegionMaster ON RegionMaster.RegionId = R.ID